# S.No not getting refreshed when clicking on page "2" in pagination link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I want to display all standards in my view. But it should display 10 records per page. so I used `will_pagination` to handle this case. When I click first page, it displayed first 10 records of standards with S.No . But When I click second page, the S.No of 11th record shows "1". But the S.No should be 11 for the 11th record. It's not working. what will be the issue?

**Controller:**

```
@standards = Standard.select("standards.standard_id, standards.standard_name")
                     .where("standards.org_id = ?", org_id)
@standards =  @standards.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
```

**View:**

```
    <% if (@standards != nil && @standards.length > 0) then%>
        <% @standards.each.with_index(1) do |standard,index| %>
          <tr>
            <td> <%= index %></td>
            <td> <%= standard.standard_name %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
        <div class="text-right">
          <% if @standards != nil then%>
            <%= will_paginate @standards, :class => 'pagination-xs',  renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
          <%end%>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the param value to get the serial number:

```
<% count = ((params[:page] || 1).to_i - 1) * 10 %>

<% if (@standards != nil && @standards.length > 0) then%>
  <% @standards.each.with_index do |standard,index| %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= count + index %></td>
      <td> <%= standard.standard_name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <div class="text-right">
    <% if @standards != nil then%>
      <%= will_paginate @standards, :class => 'pagination-xs',  renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
    <%end%>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE**

In you controller code:

```
@standards.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
```

You are saying that you need 10 records per page and you have set the page number param as `params[:page]`

Initially we are not getting any `params` since it is page 1. So if no param value is received we have to take it as 1.

```
params[:page] || 1
```

In that case `count = (1-1)*10 = 0`

Consider you are on the second page and let your URL be like this:

```
localhost:3000/standards?page=2
```

Now you have `params[:page] = 2`

And `count = (2 - 1)*10 = 10`

So `10` will be added to the serial number of each record in the second page .

Comment: Hey man..thanks a lot..this solved my problem. but i dont understand that what r you trying to say in count. could you explain me?

Comment: @AnitaShalu : I have updated the answer for better understanding. Accept the answer if it solved the issue.

Comment: but still i face a new problem. first 10 records starts with S.No 1 to 10. when I click second page it starts 11.. but when I click 3rd page it starts with 21. why so??

Comment: What is the problem there? First element in the 3rd page should have S.No 21, right. It will be like: First page(1-10), Second page(11-20), Third page(21-30) and so on.

Comment: Wait a mint pls..let me check one more time

Comment: hey man..thanks a lot..there is no issue in it. now i could understand your code clearly..BTW thanks a lot..i upvoted ur answer